# How to get the selected value?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I can't get this to work. How to get the selected value?

My Code :

```
<select name="category" id="category" >
    <option value="All Student">All Student<?php echo "(".$count.")";?></option>
    <option value="By Name">By Name</option>
    <option value="By Date">By Date</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#category').change(function(){
        if ($(this).val() == 'All Student') {
            <?php echo "haha";?>
        } else if ($(this).val() == 'By Name') {
            <?php echo "hehe";?>
        }
    });
</script>
```

Help me with this. Thanks in advance

Comment: `if ($(this).val() == 'All Student') { <?php echo "haha";?> }` that's useful..

Comment: a `>` is missing for `script`

Comment: Funny how an answer popped up so quickly after your comment @RC.

Comment: @chanchal118 Your edit to actually "fix" the problem was rolled back to Dagon's edit. **DO NOT edit original posted code**, as it could be the very fact and root of the problem.

Comment: Strange how vampires get fed. However, it is rather late so I guess it's normal for this time of the night ;-) @RC.

Comment: Another Revision "FIX" edit. (groan)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#category').change(function(){
       if ($(this).val() == 'All Student') {
         alert("haha");
       } else if ($(this).val() == 'By Name') {
        alert("hehe");
       }
     });
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Php will execute on the server side , Java script will execute on client side (browser),Don't merge both . Just try    `alert` Instated of `php echo`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the closing of the tags itself.
The php function will still run if you are **running it on a localhost server**. `alert()` or `console.log` is still better for JavaScript debugging, though I understand you probably want to send something through PHP.

The problem is that you have forgotten to open and close the script tags properly.
It should be

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//The rest of your code here
</script>
```